# How do search engines handle <noscript>?

Tags: seo, javascript, noscript

On my site, I have something like the following:

```
<noscript>
    <p>
         <strong>JavaScript is currently disabled.</strong>
         Please enable it for a better experience on this site.
    </p>
</noscript>
```

Will Google ignore this, or would this content be seen as part of my page's content, or even show up in the page description on a search results page?

Answer (score 8):

That is valid page content and the search engines will see and index it. It is even possible for it to show up as your page's description in the search results page. But there are other places that Google prefers to get a page's description from include the meta description tag, ODP description, and relative content from the page. So if that content is what is showing in your page description in the search engines you have larger SEO issues at play.

Comment: do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Christofian Google is known to change the Title and Snippets in their search results if they feel they can create a more relevant result from other copy on your page. You may consider redirecting users who do not have javascript enabled rather than displaying cnotent like you are doing now. For example view adwords without javascript and see how Google uses the tag to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 1):

Googler, JohnMu, said in a thread, "the problems with noscript is that it's been abused quite a bit by spammers, so search engines might treat it with some suspicion."

John Mueller is a Webmaster Trends Analyst at Google

Full article http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/022411.html

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue from my last website, which google used `<noscript>` content as page search result snippet.

in my case, my website is ASP.Net,
so I resolved the issue, by adding **id** & **runat=server** attributes to `<noscript>` tag,
and then in **page_load** function of MasterPage code section I controlled the visibility of this tag depending on **Request.Browser.Crawler** state.

Request.Browser.Crawler (boolean) in asp.net will identify whether the user browser is search engine web crawler or not. (of course all crawler engines are not defined in asp.net by default, and you should manually control them)